# how my code execution dependent on staging server

Tags: java, itext

I'm using itextpdf for coverting html to pdf in my application.

it is taking a lot of time to parse.

so we figured that when we start up our staging server it takes normal time otherwise it takes lot of time to parse.

I don't understand how is it possible that my local and production server dependent on staging server.

**and the dependency of maven are

```
<dependency>
        <groupId>com.itextpdf.tool</groupId>            
        <artifactId>xmlworker</artifactId>          
        <version>5.5.13</version>   
</dependency>       
<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.itextpdf/itextpdf -->          
<dependency>
        <groupId>com.itextpdf</groupId>             
        <artifactId>itextpdf</artifactId>             
        <version>5.5.13</version>
</dependency>



try{

    StringWriterrenderedDataHTML=newStringWriter();
    getTemplate().process(templateInputMap,renderedDataHTML);
    Stringhtml1=renderedDataHTML.toString();
    FiletempPdfFile=newFile(pdfDestinationDir+pdfFileName);
    try(OutputStreamos=newFileOutputStream(tempPdfFile)){
        DocumentpdfDocument=newDocument(PageSize.A3);
        PdfWriterpdfWriter=PdfWriter.getInstance(pdfDocument,os);
        pdfDocument.open();
        StringhtmlText=html1;//yourmethodthatreturnsHTMLas//
        XMLWorkerHelper.getInstance().parseXHtml(
            pdfWriter,pdfDocument, 
            newByteArrayInputStream(
                htmlText.getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8)),
                    StandardCharsets.UTF_8,

            newXMLWorkerFontProvider(
                XMLWorkerFontProvider.DONTLOOKFORFONTS));
       pdfDocument.close();
       pdfWriter.close();

    }catch(IOException|DocumentException|TemplateExceptione){
        //TODOAuto-generatedcatchblock
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Comment: Are there any references to the staging server in the `htmlText`? Are any of the paths pointing to shares on the staging server? Have you added log statements in your method to determine which part of your method takes all that time?

Comment: yes,we added the logs it taking time while parsing the data.  but finally we figured out we used image url in our html that refer to staging server. Thanks for ur response.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally we figured out we used image url in our html file that refers to staging server.